# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges on Oracle 11g on installing two times

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I will say directly First i tried to install oracle 11g and forgot to update password in password management during the installation so i followed a youtube video to uninstall oracle 11g completely.  Then i installed it a second time but during installation the setup said already a db name orcl exists.
and now when i tried this command `sys/oracle as sysdba` it throws me the following error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

and also it asks me a user-name i dont have any username or password.

I am new to Oracle database.  I usually work with H2 DB.
What can i do ? un install or does anyone knows any solution

Comment: Do a [password reset](https://serverfault.com/questions/135488/recovering-oracle-admin-password?rq=1).

Comment: Why are you installing an old, out-of-support version (11g)?  Uninstalling just because your can't remember a password is like tearing your house down and rebuilding just because you lost the door key. Installing the oracle software and creating a database are two separate and distinct operations, even though the installer gives the option of combining them. You can drop and create databases separately from the installer.

Comment: Hi @EdStevens i have a requirement in oracle 11g that's why i am using that version i know 19c is the newest among all. Ok can you say what is the procedure for dropping the databsase?

Comment: You need to update your original to state what OS this is on.  You said "i tried this command sys/oracle as sysdba", but that is not a command.  It looks like a connection string (command line parms) for sqlplus.  You need to confirm.  Have you googled "ora-01031 insufficient privileges as sysdba"?

Comment: Hi @EdStevens I solved the problem  by giving user name as sys / as sysdba and left the password empty. and it showed me access granted.  Thanks and i also finished my customer requirement.

Comment: Actually, whdben you specify 'as sysdba' (for a local connection) it doesn't matter what you enter for credentials.  You could enter 'sqlplus fubar/thisismessedup as sysdba'.  What is in play here for sysdba connections, is that if you are logged on the the OS as a member of the 'dba' (linux) or 'oracle_dba' (windows) groups, the credentials will be ignored and you will be authenticated because of your membership in the dba group.  This is referred to as 'OS authentication'